# Enforcing sequential behavior in parse promises with the 'then' method

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I'm trying to direct the sequential calling of my functions using promises but it's just not working out.

```
var step2 = function(results){
   var promise = [];
   _.each(results, function(n){
       query.equalTo("thing", n);
       query.find({
            success: function(moreStuff){
               moreStuff.set("update", "matters");
               promise.push(moreStuff);
            }
       })
    })
    return Parse.Object.saveAll(promise);
    //I've also tried:
    //Parse.Object.saveAll(promise); (no return)
}

var step3 = function(){
   //the function I want to begin only after step 2 ends
}

var step1 = function(){
     query.find().then(function(results){
        return Parse.Promise.when(step2(results)) 
   }).then(function(){
         //only after step2 finishes should step3 begin
         step3();
   })
}
```

Right now step3 begins before step2 finishes.

Here are a few additional iterations of step1 that I've tried:

```
var step1A = function(){
         query.find().then(function(results){
            step2(results)
            return Parse.Promise.when(step2)
            //I also tried this without the return 
       }).then(function(){
             //should only after step2 finishes but doesn't
             step3();
       })
    }


var step1B = function(){
         query.find({
            success: function(results){
               step2(results)
               Parse.Promise.when(step2);
               //I also tried:
               //return Parse.Promise.when(step2);
            }
          }).then(function(){
             //should only after step2 finishes but doesn't
               step3();
       })   
    }



var step1C = function(){
         query.find({
            success: function(results){
               step2(results)
               //I also tried:
               //return Parse.Promise.when(step2);

               Parse.Promise.when(step2).then(function(){
             //should only after step2 finishes but doesn't
               step3();            
               })   
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Did I miss something obvious with using this? Where am I going wrong? I've been all over the Parse docs looking for an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think a major issue with this is that the promise in step2 exists outside a Parse query and is not fully endowed with Parse promise functionality.  Is there something to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that because `query.find()` is asynchronous, your `promises` variable is nothing but an empty array when this line executes:

```
return Parse.Object.saveAll(promise);
```

If you pass it an empty array, there's nothing to save and therefore nothing to await before calling `step3`.

I'm not all that familiar with Parse.com, but I believe the following should work:

```
var step2 = function(results){
    var promises = 
        _.map(results, function(n){
            query.equalTo("thing", n);
            return query.find().then(function (moreStuff) {
                moreStuff.set("update", "matters");
                return moreStuff;
            });
        });

    return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function () {
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    });
};

var step3 = function(){
    //the function I want to begin only after step 2 ends
};

var step1 = function(){
    query.find().then(step2).then(step3);
};
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.   The promise array is not empty and Step2 does what it's supposed to do.  My only concern is step3 starting before Step2 finishes.

Comment: @rashadb this looks to me like a correct answer.  It could be more compete by showing how to execute: `step2(results).then(function() { step3(); });`, but it's fundamentally right.  The only thing wrong in your posted code was its failure to properly handle the promises being generated by the `find()` in the loop.

Comment: @rashadb, remember that a function does two things (1) (optionally) performs side-effects and (2) returns something (or `undefined`). I'm guessing that your original `step2()` performs its side-effects but either returns a non-promise or a promise that settles too early.

Comment: What does that mean 'settles too early'? step2 savesAll correctly so I think that the saveAll is not an issue. Even so, step3 begins before step2 finishes . . .

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question - in this context what are 'arguments'. I don't think it is results.

Comment: `arguments` are the arguments passed into the `then` handler on the line right above where `arguments` is used. Parse.com's `.when()` creates a promise that passes its values into the `.then()` handler as individual arguments, so I'm using `arguments` in order to handle them as an array.